# ASP.NET MVC: Routing needs exact url to work

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a `Products` Controller with `Details` action that has an Id and Slug that works as follows:

```
     routes.MapRoute(
            "ProductDetails", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}/{title}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Products", action = "Details", id = "", title = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
            );
        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );
```

The url: `localhost/Products/Details/1` and `localhost/Products/Details/1/my-slug` works.
But putting `ProductDetails` route at the top breaks my whole application. To get to my home page, my url has to look like: `localhost/Home/Index`.

`localhost/Home` or any controller of that matter does not work. It asks for a nullable parameter to be in those actions.

The error:

`The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'id' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Details(Int32)' in 'MyProject.Controllers.ProductsController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "ProductDetails", // Route name
            "Products/{action}/{id}/{title}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Products", action = "Details", id = "", title = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
            );
```

The route you defined matches to every URL before the default URL. You have given default values to controller and action fields. When you call http://localhost, it looks for ProductsController's Details method and finds it. Since id has a empty string value, you get the null exception.

The route above has constraint. It matches URLs starting with `"Products"` literal. So it doesn't break your default route.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a number constraints (\d) to the first route would solve the problem, since the route on the top would be useless without a valid id.

Comment: I just did that. It worked, thanks. Why is that so? Could you explain in a step of how those 2 routes work?

Comment: Since th route  localhost/Home matches both the route definitions you have defined and the route route  localhost/Home doesn't have id component of URL you are getting the exception as the MVC framework is trying to assign a null because of absence of ID parameter and Int32 can't have a null value assigned.